# How to instrument Oracle 10g to get table access metrics?

Tags: oracle, testing, monitoring, legacy, instrumentation

We have a legacy/production database. It has been in continuous development and use backing a website that has evolved over 10 years. The database is accessed by multiple technologies - perl cgi, php and java webapps.

Lots of cruft has accumulated. I wish to undertake a major refactoring. I am sure some parts are completely legacy (the obvious ones being tables with zero rows). To determine which parts are most used my preferred strategy is to instrument the database rather than go through a very large number of potential accessing components.

**Does oracle (10g) have the capability to put a trigger on each table to report when and how often it is accessed? Can someone point me to how to do this or some other mechanism to achieve the same goal?**

(Please comment with suggestions for other strategies to aid a database refactoring in this senario too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to know which tables are accessed (or even if you want more details) then the easiest way would be to use Oracle's built-in AUDIT functionality.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm#i2059073).

Bear in mind that some database objects may only be used quarterly or even annually.  So you really need a decent set of documentation or a suite of regression tests with 100% coverage.  Of course if you had either of those you probably wouldn't be asking your question here :)

Comment: +1 Don't assume that just because something hasn't been accessed in the last X amount of time that it won't be accessed in the future.

Comment: And don't assume an "unused" table isn't referenced by, for example, pl/sql.  Some PL/SQL may avoid TYPE declarations, prefering to declare variables or collections with the %ROWTYPE syntax.  The DBA_DEPENDENCIES view can help show which static dependencies exist; there's no help but scanning DBA_SOURCE and praying to find dynamic dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 10g and have TABLE MONITORING turned on for tables you can easily access DBA_ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.

It holds information about modifications to tables including the approximate number of inserts, updates, and deletes to a table since last analyze.

Some info on turning Table Monitoring on and a query to calculate the percentage change is here: [link](http://ba6.us/node/158)